# ASP.Net Web API vs WCF - Can the Web API be used to provide REST-based communication to a singleton WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing set of singleton WCF services. They are long-running processes that do a lot of work on an ongoing basis and expose themselves with WCF service contracts for communication with other processes.

When the WCF Web API was being developed I was excited because it was looking like I'd finally be able to do away with all of the annoying contract stuff and simply provide a platform-agnostic REST API for each service and have the processes communicate via HTTP requests and JSON responses.

Now it looks like the Web API has become an IIS-hosted ASP.Net feature, leaving me trying to figure out if I'm just missing something or if my WCF services will no longer have the opportunity to provide a REST interface.

If the Web API is no longer really targeted at my scenario, what has the ASP.Net team envisioned with respect to non-terminating singleton processes that wish to provide an HTTP/JSON-based API to other consuming processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to host ASP.NET Web API services in IIS. There is an option called "[Self Hosting](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api)" that will allow you to host your API services in another process (such as a Windows Service) if you would like. I imagine that your current architecture would work just fine as a self-hosted app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! [`HttpSelfHostServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is in the beta release of the [MVC 4 Web API components](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Answer (score 1):

You can self-host using [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) as in [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/570190/175679). Essentially - IIS is not a requirement for WCF hosting.

If you are using [`webHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) - you just need to create the [`WebServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx) which extends from `ServiceHost` to support REST.