# Run a webservice inside a windows service not IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

creating my first webservice and need some assistance. i'm trying to create a web service to send data on a machine that doesn't have IIS. I have seen examples of this on msdn [Host web service outside IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529311.aspx).

My question so far is the address for the web server as the one in the example uses `Http://localhost/WSEHostedWebService`, i'm not sure what to use here as there is no web application or even IIS running on the intended machine. Should this point to a directory on the intended machine i.e. `c:\webservice\myFirstService.asmx` ?

Comment: Doesn't it say? soap.tcp://localhost/TestService

Comment: yes, you are correct, don't know how i missed that. Thanks

Comment: You do not want to use this example. You should never use WSE (Web Service Enhancements). That is a very obsolete technology. You should use WCF, which is quite capable of being hosted in a Windows Service, with no difficulty (and not being obsolete and unsupported).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote them "The following code example creates a Windows service named WindowsServiceToHostASMXWebService that hosts a Web service named Service at the soap.tcp://localhost/Service endpoint." - Try saying that fast with a mouth full of water :D

Anyhoo, unless you specifically need ye olde worlde asmx service do it in a WCF web service inside a windows service instead [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570190/how-can-i-deploy-my-wcf-service-without-iis) and [this other link with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751414.aspx)

As the link above says WCF handles the HTTP stuff outside of IIS anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this rather, seems to be more inline what i'm trying to do